# Html Binding to Dynamic Content

Tags: jquery, ajax, knockout.js, observable

I have the following markup:

```
<div id="metro-hub">
    <h1 id="hub-title" data-bind="text: hubTitle" class="hub-title">@Model.HubTitle</h1>
    <div id="hubWrapper" data-root-url="/Root" data-bind="html: currentHub"></div>
</div>
```

I am using KnockoutJS to bind a `viewModel` JavaScript object to the view. I also created a custom binding to hookup the navigation to a sitemap on the server. Below are some snippets from what I've got so far:

```
var MetroPageViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.currentHub = ko.observable();
    self.viewPortData = ko.observable();
    self.hubTitle = ko.observable();

    self.renderHub = function (rootUrl) {
        console.log(rootUrl);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Base/NewHub',
            type: 'get',
            data: {
                url: rootUrl
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data) {
                    var wrappedData = $(data);
                    var newHubContent = wrappedData.find('ul');
                    var title = wrappedData.find('input.metro-hub-title').val();
                    self.hubTitle(title);
                    self.currentHub(newHubContent); //THIS IS THE LINE THAT DOES NOT WORK
                }
            }
        });
    };

    self.initialize = function () {
        var url = $('#hubWrapper').data('root-url');
        self.renderHub(url);
    };
};

$(function () {
    var viewModel = new MetroPageViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    viewModel.initialize();
});
```

And here's the custom binding that uses the Sammy.js library to do routing based on the url hash:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.metroHub = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var menuItems = $(element).find('li');
        Sammy(function () {
            var $this = this;
            menuItems.each(function (index, elem) {
                $this.get('#/' + $(elem).data('link-name'), function () {
                    var numChildren = $(elem).data('num-children');
                    if (numChildren > 0) {
                       var rootUrl = (elem).data('source-url');
                       viewModel.renderHub(rootUrl);
                    } else {
                        var dataSource = $(elem).data('source-url');
                        $.ajax({
                            url: dataSource,
                            type: 'get',
                            success: function (data) {
                                if (data) {
                                    viewModel.viewPortData(data);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
            var firstItem = menuItems[0];
            var itemRoute = '#/' + $(firstItem).data('link-name');
            $this.get('', function () { this.app.runRoute('get', itemRoute) });
        }).run();
    }
};
```

The data being returned from the server is as follows:

```
<div><ul class="metro-menu" data-bind="metroHub: true"><li data-link-name="Home" data-num-children="0" data-source-url="/Navigation/Item1"><a href="#/Home">Home</a></li><li data-link-name="Products" data-num-children="2" data-source-url="/Navigation/Item2"><a href="#/Products">Products</a></li><li data-link-name="Services" data-num-children="0" data-source-url="/Navigation/Item3"><a href="#/Services">Services</a></li></ul>
<input class="metro-hub-title" type="hidden" value="this is a hub title"></input>
<input class="hasParentNode" type="hidden" value="False"></input>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**

Now the problem is that the custom binding `update` callback is not being triggered once the AJAX callback in the `renderHub()` method returns. Do I need to call some method to force the binding or anything?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should place the update-binding on the parent container since that control is being updated.

I think the update isn't firing is because the old div which should respond to an update is completely replaced by new html.

You could do a quick check if I'm right by creating a init function in your binding with the same code as the update.